# How to get arraylist data from servlet to jsp using ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I called a servlet through ajax call on widow.load() event ..But when i want to show the value got after success of ajax call in alert box it is showing [object XMLDocument] i dont know why .this is the first time i am using ajax call.

Here is my ajax call code...`

```
$(window).load(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'Sites',
            datatype:'text',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                debugger;
                var city=data;
                for(var i in city)
                {
                    output ='<input type="checkbox"   id="'+city[i]+'" name="'+city[i]+'" value="'+city[i]+'" />'+city[i]+'<br />'
                }
                console.log(output)
            }
        });
    });
```

And here is my servlet code from where i sending data in arraylist formate.

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    ArrayList calltype = new ArrayList();

    try {
        String strQuery = "";
        ResultSet rs = null;

        conexion conexiondb = new conexion();
        conexiondb.Conectar();

        strQuery = "Select * from sites";

        rs = conexiondb.Consulta(strQuery);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String toc = rs.getString("sites");
            calltype.add(toc);
        }

        out.print(calltype);
        System.out.println(calltype);
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // display stack trace in the browser
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Any help on this will be appreciated ..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you sure your ajax call going to servlet?

Comment: @VinothKrishnan yes it is going to servlet ..from firebug firebug status its OK and response is also coming for site name like [Mumbai, Delhi, Bangalore]

Comment: make your `dataType : "text"` or `dataType : "html"`. This will returns text. For more information read [jQuery Ajax Article](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: @VinothKrishnan thank you very much sir now values of city is showing in alertbox but it is not going inside the loop to dynamically make checkbox please check my script code..

Comment: @Adi What does it alret?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Adi what are the values you are receiving in data, like [mumbai,chennai]? Store this values in javascript array variable. Like

```
var values = [];
values = data;
```

Then you can use jquery `.each()` [jQuery each function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate through each cities.

```
$.each(values, function( index, value ) {
   alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

I haven't checked this code. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: thank you very much sir will u please share a link for .each() function of jquery

Comment: I edited my answer. you can do like that.

Comment: Sir i want to break this array values based on comma

Comment: Dude, have you tried the `$.each()` function? It is the best way to bring out your values from array. I hope you don't want index, but you can get the cities from your value inside function(each function)

Comment: I have just [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7EjT2/) it. You can verify your data is working on iteration.